# What is the probability that $a$ is more than $c$ times larger than $b$?

Tags: probability

> Let $a,b$ be two arbitrary positive real numbers and let $c$ be constant positive real number. What is the probability that $a$ is more than $c$ times larger than $b$?

This is my solution:
Because $\text{probability}=\frac{\text{number of cases with these features}}{\text{number of all cases}}$, I first tried to find number of all cases. Let $n\to\infty$, then $a$ can be in interval $(0,n)$ and $b$ can be in interval $(0,n)$, so
$$\text{number of all cases}=\int_0^n\int_0^ndadb$$
Then I tried to find number of cases when $a>cb$:
$$\text{number of cases with these features}=\int_0^n\int_{cb}^ndadb$$
After that, I just divided these numbers:
$$\text{probability}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\int_0^n\int_{cb}^ndadb}{\int_0^n\int_0^ndadb}=\frac{2-c}2$$
For $c=1$ it is obviously true. But what about $c>2$? Is it possible that possibility can be negative, or my solution is incorrect?

Comment: The "number of cases" thing should only be used for variables with finite equiprobable outcomes.

Comment: @leonbloy. Yes, I know, but I didn't know how to say it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

draw some pictures of the space you are integrating over and you will see that
if $c\geq 1$ then this probability is $\displaystyle \frac{\frac12 n \frac{n}{c}}{n^2}=\frac{1}{2c}$ and if $c< 1$ then this probability is $\displaystyle 1-\frac{\frac12 n \times cn}{n^2}=1-\frac{c}{2}$.

$c\geq 1$; the ratio of blue area to the square (for simplicity $n=10$):

[image]

$c< 1$; 1 minus the ratio of white area to the square (for simplicity $n=10$):

[image]

---

Let $c>1$
\begin{align}
p&=\frac{\int_0^t\int_{cb}^ndadb}{n^2}\\
\end{align}
since $cb<a$ we clearly have $b<\frac{a}{c}$ but since $a<n$ we have that $b<\frac{n}{c}$. Therefore the limit for $b$ should be adjusted, i.e. $t=n/c$:
\begin{align}
p&=\frac{\int_0^{n/c}\int_{cb}^ndadb}{n^2}=\frac{1}{2c}\\
\end{align}

Comment: Please see the edit.